# CamelCase a string - python

Tags: python

I have a string for example
 `ST. PETER'S HOSPITAL OF DEMIGARGON, LLC.` And many more such strings where the space , comma `,` and fullstop `.` positions are random.

A desired output is - `St. Peter's Hospital Of Demigargon, LLC.`

whats the best way to achieve this?

This is what I tried so far

```
for row in ws.iter_rows(min_row=2):
    split = row[0].value.split()
    finalname = ""
    for i, item in enumerate(split):

        if item != 'LLC':
            finalname+=item.title()
        else:
            finalname+= item

        if i != len(split) - 1:
            finalname+=" "

      print(finalname)
```

Comment: You can use `.title()`, but it will convert `"LLC"` and `"'S"`, too.

Comment: Did you mean for `OF` to stay capitalized?

Comment: @gilch its `Of` Updated. sorry

Comment: @DYZ ``S` can be converted to smaller case too `'s`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to do it manually:

```
IGNORED_STRINGS = [
   'LLC.'
]

def to_camel_case(string_val):
  if string_val in IGNORED_STRINGS:
    return string_val
  else:
    return string_val[0] + (string_val[1:]).lower()


sample_string = "ST. PETER'S HOSPITAL OF DEMIGARGON, LLC."


camel_cased_string = " ".join([
    to_camel_case(string_val) 
    for string_val in sample_string.split(' ')
])

print(camel_cased_string)
```

I've added `IGNORED_STRINGS` so you can add any special cases, i.e. `LLC.`

Answer (score 0):

```
"ST. PETER'S HOSPITAL OF DEMIGARGON, LLC.".title().replace('Llc','LLC').replace("'S", "'s")
```

This just treats the `Llc` and `'S` as special cases.

You can get a bit more advanced with regex. `re.sub()` can take an arbitrary function to compute the replacements from the match object.

```
import re

IGNORED = {"LLC."}  # Add other special cases as needed.
string = "ST. PETER'S HOSPITAL OF DEMIGARGON, LLC."

def repl(m):
    if m.group() in IGNORED:
        return m.group()
    return m.group(1) + m.group(2).lower()  # Unlike .title(), works on "PETER'S".

re.sub("(\w)(\S*)", repl, string)  # groups: (1st letter)(not spaces)
```

Comment: There are probably other special cases.